# Calling await on a task created with Task.Run()

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, async-await

Why is it possible to do this in C#?

```
var task = Task.Run (...);
await task;
```

Isn't `Task.Run()` supposed to be used for CPU-bound code? Does it make sense to call `await`for this?

I.e., after calling `Task.Run` I understand that the task is running in another thread of the thread pool. What's the purpose of calling `await`? Wouldn't make more sense just to call `task.Wait()`?

One last question, my first impression was that `await` is intended to be used exclusively with `async` methods. Is it common to use it for task returned by `Task.Run()`?

EDIT. It also makes me wonder, why do we have `Task.Wait ()` and not a `Task.Await()`. I mean, why a method is used for `Wait()` and a keyworkd for `await`. Wouldn't be more consistent to use a method in both cases?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There would be no point at all in using `Wait`.  There's no point in starting up a new thread to do work if you're just going to have another thread sitting there doing nothing waiting on it.  The only sensible option of those two is to `await` it.  Awaiting a task is entirely sensible, as it's allowing the original thread to continue execution.

It's sensible to `await` any type of `Task` (in the right context), regardless of where it comes from.  There's nothing special about `async` methods being awaited.  In fact in every single asynchronous program there needs to be asynchronous methods that aren't using the `async` keyword; if every `await` is awaiting an `async` method then you'll never have anywhere to start.

Comment: Maybe I didn't read the right documentation. But it seems the documentation is always given as is async/await were an inseparable couple, wich is wrong.

Comment: @sapito You can only ever `await` in a method that is itself marked as `async`.  What you await can be any `Task`, regardless of whether or not it was generated using `async` or not.

Comment: Thanks, I understand now. I guess I can also call `Task.Wait()` with the task returned by async methods.

Comment: @sapito That's virtually always wrong.  You should almost never be synchronously waiting on asynchronous operations.

Comment: So how should I implement it if I want to "freeze" my application till an async task is completed?

Comment: @sapito You shouldn't be so cruel as to want to do that to your users, ever.  If you want to disable certain controls in the UI then disable those controls; don't freeze the message loop and make the entire application unresponsive.

Comment: You are right. But just curious if it would work. I understand it would work, but I shouldn't use it.

Answer (score 4):

There are several good answers here, but from a more philosophical standpoint...

If you have lots of CPU-bound work to do, the best solution is usually the Task Parallel Library, i.e., `Parallel` or Parallel LINQ.

If you have I/O-bound work to do, the best solution is usually `async` and `await` code that is built around naturally-asynchronous implementations (e.g., `Task.Factory.FromAsync`).

`Task.Run` is a way to execute a *single* piece of CPU-bound code and treat it as asynchronous from the point of view of the calling thread. I.e., if you want to do CPU-bound work but not have it interfere with the UI.

The construct `await Task.Run` is a way to bridge the two worlds: have the UI thread queue up CPU-bound work and treat it asynchronously. This is IMO the best way to bridge asynchronous and parallel code as well, e.g., `await Task.Run(() => Parallel.ForEach(...))`.

> why a method is used for Wait() and a keyword for await.

One reason that `await` is a keyword is because they wanted to enable pattern matching. Tasks are not the only "awaitables" out there. WinRT has its own notion of "asynchronous operations" which are awaitable, Rx observable sequences are awaitable, `Task.Yield` returns a non-Task awaitable, and this enables you to create your own awaitables if necessary (e.g., [if you want to avoid `Task` allocations in high-performance socket applications](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/12/15/10248293.aspx)).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's common and recommended. `await` allows to wait for a task (or any awaitable) **asynchronously**. It's true that it's mostly used for naturally asynchronous operations (e.g. I/O), but it's also used for offloading work to be done on a different thread using `Task.Run` and waiting asynchronously for it to complete.

Using `Wait` not only blocks the calling thread and so defeats the purpose of using `Task.Run` in the first place, it could also potentially lead to deadlocks in a GUI environment with a single threaded synchronization context.

> One last question, my first impression was that await is intended to be used exclusively with async methods

Whether a method is actually marked with the `async` modifier is an implementation detail and most "root" task returning methods in .Net aren't actually `async` ones (`Task.Delay` is a good example for that).

Comment: Why a deadlock? Isn't `Task.Run` supposed to run ALWAYS on a separate thread? I thought it was meant for CPU-bound tasks.

Comment: @sapito `Task.Run` would use a different thread, but calling `Wait` on the first thread, the calling thread will block that thread until the task completes. In a GUI environment that would cause a deadlock.

Answer (score 1):

> Wouldn't make more sense just to call task.Wait()?

No, if you call `Wait` you're involving two threads there, one of the worker threads from the *ThreadPool* is working for you (given the task is CPU bound), and also your calling thread will be blocked.

Why would you block the calling thread? The result will be too bad if the calling thread is a UI thread! Also if you call `Task.Run` immediately followed by `Task.Wait` you're making it worse, too. It is no better than calling the delegate synchronously. There is no point whatsoever in calling `Wait` immediately after starting a Task.

You should almost never use `Wait`, always prefer `await` and release the calling thread.

Answer (score 0):

It is very common and useful for cases like (greatly simplified; production code would need exception handling, for instance):

```
async void OnButtonClicked()
{
   //... Get information from UI controls ...
   var results = await Task.Run(CpuBoundWorkThatShouldntBlockUI);
   //... Update UI based on results from work run in the background ...
}
```

Regarding the comment of your later edit, 'await' is not a method call.  It is a keyword (only allowed in a method that has been marked 'async', for clarity) that the compiler uses to decide how to implement the method.  Under the hood, this involves rewriting the method procedure as a state machine that can be paused every time you use the 'await' keyword, then resumed when whatever is it awaiting calls back to indicate that it is done.  This is a simplified description (exception propagation and other details complicate things), but the key point is that 'await' does a lot more than just calling a method on a Task.

In previous C# versions, the closest construct to this 'async/await' magic was the use of 'yield return' to implement `IEnumerable<T>`.  For both enumerations and async methods, you want a way to pause and resume a method.  The async/await keywords (and associated compiler support) start with this basic idea of a resumable method, then add in some powerful features like automatic propagation of exceptions, dispatching callbacks via a synchronization context (mostly useful to keep code on the UI thread) and automatic implementation of all the glue code to set up the continuation callback logic.